# CSS universal layout

Tags: html, css

By universal I mean a HTML mark-up that remains (almost) the same for multiple layout types. Almost, because there would be layouts where one or two columns are missing, so they won't be present in the mark-up (eg. sidebars).

I found one here:
http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm

It works for the fixed / fluid type of layouts, but I was wondering if it's possible to make it work with fixed side-columns, and fluid main column too.

Are you aware of any other solution that might meet this requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it pure CSS, you will need the css calc to do somthing like this:

```
width: calc(100% - 150px)
```

Calc is in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc) but, isn't inplented yet

So you will need to do it in Javacript:

```
$('#main').width($(document).width()-150);
```

a fall-back CSS is required to not make it look broken in browsers without JS enabled

Answer (score 2):

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-3-column-holy-grail-pixels.htm

in the upper right corner there you can change the type to: px, em and %

---

Newer version: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/holy-grail-no-quirks-mode.htm